# How to stack sprite elements without being dropped thru object

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to stack some sprites, let's say that they're boxes, but when I stack more than 5, the lowest ones fall thru the supporting object, as if the weight of the group was too much heavy.

The idea is to stack as many boxes as wanted, but it seems that I'm missing something to tell to the physics engine.

You can see the working code here: https://codepen.io/dlaguna/pen/xMyzVW

```
var config = {
type: Phaser.AUTO,
width: 600,
height: 500,
physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      debug: true,
      gravity: { y: 200 }
    }
},
scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
}
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('ground', 'https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BzpfI1EyL4A/WrA98ayD7ZI/AAAAAAAABFA/Z1gjrdLqtRsG5O2Lp_n2odf0n_G-MVLQgCLcBGAs/s400/cccam%2Bspot.PNG');
    this.load.image('box', 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8P5hVl0_rHaIVjVJcIVXvdsQtKJGOzW92KvuoDvaitnRX2POiWQ');
}

function create ()
{
  this.ground = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 470, 'ground');
  this.ground.setImmovable(true);
  this.ground.body.setAllowGravity(false);

  this.stack = this.physics.add.group();
  this.physics.add.collider( this.stack, this.ground);

  this.elem = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 425, 'box').setScale(2);
  this.elem.setMass(0.2);
  this.physics.add.collider( this.elem, this.stack);
  this.stack.add( this.elem );

  let numElems = 6;
  for (let i = 0; i < numElems; i++) {
    this.elem = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 425 - 50*(i+1), 'box').setScale(2);
    this.elem.setMass(0.2);
    this.physics.add.collider( this.elem, this.stack);
    this.stack.add( this.elem );
  }
}
```

Changing the *numElems* variable to 5 shows how the scene may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to custom separate. 
[hint here](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Ccustom%20separate.js).
It's seems to work find but not sure how exactly this is working.

```
var config = {
type: Phaser.AUTO,
width: 600,
height: 500,
physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      debug: true,
      gravity: { y: 200 }
    }
},
scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
}
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('ground', 'https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BzpfI1EyL4A/WrA98ayD7ZI/AAAAAAAABFA/Z1gjrdLqtRsG5O2Lp_n2odf0n_G-MVLQgCLcBGAs/s400/cccam%2Bspot.PNG');
    this.load.image('box', 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8P5hVl0_rHaIVjVJcIVXvdsQtKJGOzW92KvuoDvaitnRX2POiWQ');
}

function create ()
{
  this.ground = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 470, 'ground');
  this.ground.setImmovable(true);
  this.ground.body.setAllowGravity(false);

  this.stack = this.physics.add.group();
  this.physics.add.collider( this.stack, this.ground);

  let numElems = 8;
  for (let i = 0; i < numElems; i++) {
    this.elem = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 425 - 50*(i+1), 'box').setScale(2);
    this.elem.setMass(0.2);
    this.elem.customSeparateY = true;
    this.physics.add.collider(this.stack, this.elem, function (s1, s2) {
          var b1 = s1.body;
          var b2 = s2.body;

          if (b1.y > b2.y) {
              b2.y += (b1.top - b2.bottom);
              b2.stop();
          }
          else {
              b1.y += (b2.top - b1.bottom);
              b1.stop();
          }
      });

    this.stack.add( this.elem );
  }
}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```